# how to check if date is entered

Tags: c#, date

I have a method:

```
public IEnumerable<Something> MethodName(DateTime? checkin, DateTime? checkout, int year){}
```

From this method how can i check if checkin date is been entered by a user. This is what i have done but i am getting an error: I think i am not using a right operator to check date.

```
   if (checkin.HasValue){
List<Name> l =FileName.NameofMethod(checkin)
} else if (checkin.HasValue && checkout.HasValue){
List<Name> l =FileName.NameofMethod2(checkin, checkout, year)
}
```

If i am returning the list will this method work? currently i am getting an error saying:

```
Error   8   The best overloaded method match for 'ProjectName.FileName.NameofMethod(System.DateTime, System.DateTime, int)' has some invalid arguments
```

And i am also getting error of:

```
Error   9   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'
```

What does that means. So if one date is selected fire a method if both date are selected then fire another method that does something else

Comment: Can you change the signature of your method to use nullable DateTimes?

Comment: when i use checkin && checkout i get an error saying Error 8 Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime' and 'System.DateTime'. This means i cannot use && with date??

Comment: Your `NameOfMethod` expects non-nullable `DateTime`s. You can use the `.Value` property for that (or cast to DateTime). Note that both will fail when the value is a null.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use DateTime? instead of DateTime type. '?' makes the DateTime nullable so if no data is entered it will contain null.

So your method signature would then look like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Something> MethodName(DateTime? checkin, DateTime? checkout, int year){}
```

You can then change you if-condition to the following:

```
if (checkin.HasValue)
{
   //do something....
} 
else if (checkin.HasValue && checkout.HasValue)
{
   //do something else...
}
```

In case you would prefer not to change the type you can compare it with DateTime.MinValue

```
if(checkin != DateTime.MinValue)
```

As this is a default value for DateTime so checkin will be assigned with this value in case a user will not set anything.

Comment: +1. Or since DateTime is a struct you could compare to default(DateTime) - just in case the framework default ever changes!

Comment: Yes, that's also possible :) But then it should be default(DateTime)